# Why is the simpleName for "Float" actually "float"?

Tags: scala

The simpleName of String is literally "String":

```
scala> "abc".getClass.getSimpleName
res0: String = String
```

That makes sense, the simpleName of the type is the same name that I use to make one up in the first place, but consider Float:

```
scala> 32.2f
res4: Float = 32.2

scala> 23.2f.getClass.getSimpleName
res3: String = float
```

I was expecting 'Float' but I got '[f]loat'  - why is the SimpleName behavior inconsistent with the representation of the object in the REPL?

Bonus points - is there a way that I can recover the exact name of the type I originally used, without any cumbersome mappings? What method is the REPL calling on the object to get it's correct name (with the capitol F).

Comment: In the case of `AnyVal` (boxed primitive) types, the simple name is the unboxed value's name - "float" for an unboxed `Float`.

Comment: @Shadowlands `AnyVal` values aren't necessarily boxed. That's the reason it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scala type:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._, universe._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._

scala> def f[A](a: A)(implicit t: TypeTag[A]) = t
f: [A](a: A)(implicit t: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]

scala> f(2.0)   // typeTag[Double]
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Double] = TypeTag[Double]

scala> res1.tpe
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Double

scala> res2.typeSymbol.name
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol#NameType = Double
```

The boxed distinction is strictly an artifact of the underlying platform.

```
scala> java.lang.Float.TYPE
res4: Class[Float] = float

scala> classOf[java.lang.Float]
res5: Class[Float] = class java.lang.Float
```

Answer (score 0):

> What method is the REPL calling on the object to get it's correct name (with the capitol F).

It isn't calling any method on the object; if it did, it couldn't show two different types for the same object:

```
scala> val x = ""
res1: String = ""

scala> val y: Object = x
res2: Object = x
```

It's using compiler's information about types which can be accessed using [`TypeTag`s](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) as som-snytt's answer shows.